# How to show Git log history (i.e., all the related commits) for a sub directory of a Git repository

Tags: git

Let’s say that I have a Git repository that looks like this:

```
foo/
  .git/
  A/
   ... big tree here
  B/
   ... big tree here
```

Is there a way to ask `git log` to show only the log messages for a specific directory? For example, I want to see what commits touched files in `foo/A` only.

Answer (score 377, accepted):

From directory `foo/`, use

```
  git log -- A
```

You need the '--' to separate `<path>..` from the `<since>..<until>` refspecs.

```
# Show changes for src/nvfs
$ git log --oneline -- src/nvfs
d6f6b3b Changes for Mac OS X
803fcc3 Initial Commit

# Show all changes (one additional commit besides in src/nvfs).
$ git log --oneline
d6f6b3b Changes for Mac OS X
96cbb79 gitignore
803fcc3 Initial Commit
```

Comment: @GoZoner, is there a way to find all commits where a specific folder name was changed? the folder could have moved around, so I would prefer not have to hunt down how and where the folder moved..

Comment: What if the directory was deleted in the current head?

Comment: keep in mind that this command will return expected results relatively to requested "path". In case of path=A you are ok if you are running from "foo/". However if you are inside "A" it will probably yield no results.

Comment: As a quick read `git log -- A` could perhaps show the minimal command that is immediately understandable without reading any explanation text, such as `git log -- folder/`

Answer (score 83):

Enter

```
git log .
```

from the specific directory. It also gives commits in that directory.

Comment: Not worked for me..After landing in specific directory and giving the git log . gave me all commits from root.

Comment: Works for me. Using git bash

Comment: This works; however, one should be especially careful when using this in combination with -n <number> to limit the number of log messages. If you accidentally type "git -n 3." instead of "git -n 3 ." (note the missing space between 3 and .), git happily displays the  history of the whole repo.

Answer (score 41):

If you want to see it graphically you can use [gitk](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk):

```
gitk -- foo/A
```

[image]

Answer (score 29):

You can use `git log` with the pathnames of the respective folders:

`git log A B`

The log will only show commits made in `A` and `B`. I usually throw in `--stat` to make things a little prettier, which helps for quick commit reviews.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers only show the changed files.

`git log -p DIR` is very useful, if you need the **full diff** of all changed files in a specific subdirectory.

Example: Show all detailed changes in a specific version range

```
git log -p 8a5fb..HEAD -- A B

commit 62ad8c5d
Author: Scott Tiger
Date:   Mon Nov 27 14:25:29 2017 +0100

    My comment

...
@@ -216,6 +216,10 @@ public class MyClass {

+  Added
-  Deleted
```

Comment: The other answers only show what OP asked for. You just added a random additional unneeded specification.

Answer (score 7):

For tracking changes to a folder where the folder was moved, I started using:

```
git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline -- "*/foo/subfoo/*"
```

This isn't perfect as it will grab other folders with the same name, but if it is unique, then it seems to work.

Comment: This is the only solution that will work if the specified path does not exist in your current work-tree. E.g. if it's only present on a bunch of topic branches.