# Link to the latest file uploaded in a GitHub repository

Tags: git, url, github, github-pages, github-api

Is there a method to get the RAW link to the latest file uploaded in a folder within a GitHub repository?

For example, here is a link (to a specific file):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/2019-nCoV/master/daily_case_updates/02-10-2020_1030.csv
```

Is there a method to get the link to most recent one?

Comment: Maybe get the latest commit in that folder and search for any file in this directory? I would write a script for that.

Comment: Using what, any ideas?

Comment: Using `git log -- <directory>` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16343950/10871900) suggests for example

Comment: Are you asking for a link that changes the file name based on which file is the most recently changed?

Comment: No although that is a solution. I will post an answer once I get to school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw this in a script

```
function reverse(collection) {
  if (typeof collection != "object") {
    return collection
  }
  return collection.reverse()
}
```

then use the following and the cell you want is always B2 `=reverse(IMPORTHTML("https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/2019-nCoV/tree/master/daily_case_updates","table", 1))`