# How to git-svn clone specific subdirectories without the extra commit logs of the parent directory?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I have an SVN directory structure like this:

```
SVN
    HEAD
        PROJECT1
            project1 files
        PROJECT2
            project2 files
        PROJECT3
            project3 files
        PROJECT4
            project4 files
        ...
```

I want to create a Git repo like this:

```
Git
    PROJECT1
        project1 files
    PROJECT2
        project2 files
```

When I execute the following commands:

```
git svn init svn://my-svn-url --trunk HEAD --include-paths='^HEAD/(PROJECT1|PROJECT2)/' my-git
cd my-git
git svn fetch
```

I get the desired Git repo structure. However, when inspecting `git log`, I notice that the entire SVN log (commit history) of HEAD is included. But I only want the SVN log of PROJECT1 and PROJECT2 to be included in the `git log` result.

Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show Git log history (i.e., all the related commits) for a sub directory of a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343659/how-to-show-git-log-history-i-e-all-the-related-commits-for-a-sub-directory) BTW, I don't think the repo having been converted from Subversion is of consequence. It's the same answer as for a vanilla Git repo.